# Google Plus login demo keeps failing connection

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I downloaded and imported the gplus-quickstart demo project from https://github.com/googleplus/gplus-quickstart-android

and I am unable to login with my g+ account, I keep getting the error "Google Play services error could not be resolved: 17"

I made no changes to the project itself other than adding two permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
```

I figured these permissions may be needed and were just forgotten. The other steps I took were the following,

1) I got the SHA fingerprint from console

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

2) I then enabled google+ API from the developers console and API section
3) I then created a new client ID from the credentials section on the developers console. I filled out the information, making sure to select "Installed application" as the application type and inputting the same package name as the demo package name, as well as the SHA I got from console.

After these steps, I ran the application and when trying to login I receive in my logs the following:

```
Google Play services error could not be resolved: 17
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Is there something in the gradle files I should fix? Do I need to make some further updates and changes? I will post my class below, maybe I have old version or something.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener,
        ResultCallback<LoadPeopleResult>, View.OnClickListener,
        CheckBox.OnCheckedChangeListener, GoogleApiClient.ServerAuthCodeCallbacks {

    private static final String TAG = "android-plus-quickstart";

    private static final int STATE_DEFAULT = 0;
    private static final int STATE_SIGN_IN = 1;
    private static final int STATE_IN_PROGRESS = 2;

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 0;

    private static final String SAVED_PROGRESS = "sign_in_progress";

    // Client ID for a web server that will receive the auth code and exchange it for a
    // refresh token if offline access is requested.
    private static final String WEB_CLIENT_ID = "WEB_CLIENT_ID";

    // Base URL for your token exchange server, no trailing slash.
    private static final String SERVER_BASE_URL = "SERVER_BASE_URL";

    // URL where the client should GET the scopes that the server would like granted
    // before asking for a serverAuthCode
    private static final String EXCHANGE_TOKEN_URL = SERVER_BASE_URL + "/exchangetoken";

    // URL where the client should POST the serverAuthCode so that the server can exchange
    // it for a refresh token,
    private static final String SELECT_SCOPES_URL = SERVER_BASE_URL + "/selectscopes";


    // GoogleApiClient wraps our service connection to Google Play services and
    // provides access to the users sign in state and Google's APIs.
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // We use mSignInProgress to track whether user has clicked sign in.
    // mSignInProgress can be one of three values:
    //
    //       STATE_DEFAULT: The default state of the application before the user
    //                      has clicked 'sign in', or after they have clicked
    //                      'sign out'.  In this state we will not attempt to
    //                      resolve sign in errors and so will display our
    //                      Activity in a signed out state.
    //       STATE_SIGN_IN: This state indicates that the user has clicked 'sign
    //                      in', so resolve successive errors preventing sign in
    //                      until the user has successfully authorized an account
    //                      for our app.
    //   STATE_IN_PROGRESS: This state indicates that we have started an intent to
    //                      resolve an error, and so we should not start further
    //                      intents until the current intent completes.
    private int mSignInProgress;

    // Used to store the PendingIntent most recently returned by Google Play
    // services until the user clicks 'sign in'.
    private PendingIntent mSignInIntent;

    // Used to store the error code most recently returned by Google Play services
    // until the user clicks 'sign in'.
    private int mSignInError;

    // Used to determine if we should ask for a server auth code when connecting the
    // GoogleApiClient.  False by default so that this sample can be used without configuring
    // a WEB_CLIENT_ID and SERVER_BASE_URL.
    private boolean mRequestServerAuthCode = false;

    // Used to mock the state of a server that would receive an auth code to exchange
    // for a refresh token,  If true, the client will assume that the server has the
    // permissions it wants and will not send an auth code on sign in.  If false,
    // the client will request offline access on sign in and send and new auth code
    // to the server.  True by default because this sample does not implement a server
    // so there would be nowhere to send the code.
    private boolean mServerHasToken = true;

    private SignInButton mSignInButton;
    private Button mSignOutButton;
    private Button mRevokeButton;
    private TextView mStatus;
    private ListView mCirclesListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mCirclesAdapter;
    private ArrayList<String> mCirclesList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        mSignInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        mSignOutButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sign_out_button);
        mRevokeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.revoke_access_button);
        mStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_status);
        mCirclesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.circles_list);

        // Button listeners
        mSignInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mSignOutButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRevokeButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        // CheckBox listeners
        ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.request_auth_code_checkbox)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.has_token_checkbox)).setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

        mCirclesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        mCirclesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.circle_member, mCirclesList);
        mCirclesListView.setAdapter(mCirclesAdapter);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSignInProgress = savedInstanceState
                    .getInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, STATE_DEFAULT);
        }

        mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    private GoogleApiClient buildGoogleApiClient() {
        // When we build the GoogleApiClient we specify where connected and
        // connection failed callbacks should be returned, which Google APIs our
        // app uses and which OAuth 2.0 scopes our app requests.
        GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(Plus.API, Plus.PlusOptions.builder().build())
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN);

        if (mRequestServerAuthCode) {
            checkServerAuthConfiguration();
            builder = builder.requestServerAuthCode(WEB_CLIENT_ID, this);
        }

        return builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(SAVED_PROGRESS, mSignInProgress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            // We only process button clicks when GoogleApiClient is not transitioning
            // between connected and not connected.
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.sign_in_button:
                    mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signing_in);
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    break;
                case R.id.sign_out_button:
                    // We clear the default account on sign out so that Google Play
                    // services will not return an onConnected callback without user
                    // interaction.
                    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                        Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                    }
                    onSignedOut();
                    break;
                case R.id.revoke_access_button:
                    // After we revoke permissions for the user with a GoogleApiClient
                    // instance, we must discard it and create a new one.
                    Plus.AccountApi.clearDefaultAccount(mGoogleApiClient);
                    // Our sample has caches no user data from Google+, however we
                    // would normally register a callback on revokeAccessAndDisconnect
                    // to delete user data so that we comply with Google developer
                    // policies.
                    Plus.AccountApi.revokeAccessAndDisconnect(mGoogleApiClient);
                    mGoogleApiClient = buildGoogleApiClient();
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        switch (buttonView.getId()) {
            case R.id.request_auth_code_checkbox:
                mRequestServerAuthCode = isChecked;
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                if (isChecked) {
                    findViewById(R.id.layout_has_token).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    findViewById(R.id.layout_has_token).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
                break;
            case R.id.has_token_checkbox:
                mServerHasToken = isChecked;
                break;
        }
    }

    /* onConnected is called when our Activity successfully connects to Google
     * Play services.  onConnected indicates that an account was selected on the
     * device, that the selected account has granted any requested permissions to
     * our app and that we were able to establish a service connection to Google
     * Play services.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Reaching onConnected means we consider the user signed in.
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");

        // Update the user interface to reflect that the user is signed in.
        mSignInButton.setEnabled(false);
        mSignOutButton.setEnabled(true);
        mRevokeButton.setEnabled(true);

        // Hide the sign-in options, they no longer apply
        findViewById(R.id.layout_server_auth).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Retrieve some profile information to personalize our app for the user.
        Person currentUser = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);

        mStatus.setText(String.format(
                getResources().getString(R.string.signed_in_as),
                currentUser.getDisplayName()));

        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null)
                .setResultCallback(this);

        // Indicate that the sign in process is complete.
        mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
    }

    /* onConnectionFailed is called when our Activity could not connect to Google
     * Play services.  onConnectionFailed indicates that the user needs to select
     * an account, grant permissions or resolve an error in order to sign in.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might
        // be returned in onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
        Log.e(TAG, "result: " + result);
        if (result.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.API_UNAVAILABLE) {
            // An API requested for GoogleApiClient is not available. The device's current
            // configuration might not be supported with the requested API or a required component
            // may not be installed, such as the Android Wear application. You may need to use a
            // second GoogleApiClient to manage the application's optional APIs.
            Log.w(TAG, "API Unavailable.");
        } else if (mSignInProgress != STATE_IN_PROGRESS) {
            // We do not have an intent in progress so we should store the latest
            // error resolution intent for use when the sign in button is clicked.
            mSignInIntent = result.getResolution();
            mSignInError = result.getErrorCode();
            Log.d(TAG, "mSignInIntent(1): " + mSignInIntent);
            Log.v(TAG, "mSignInProgress == : " + mSignInProgress);
            if (mSignInProgress == STATE_SIGN_IN) {
                // STATE_SIGN_IN indicates the user already clicked the sign in button
                // so we should continue processing errors until the user is signed in
                // or they click cancel.
                resolveSignInError();
            }
        }

        // In this sample we consider the user signed out whenever they do not have
        // a connection to Google Play services.
        onSignedOut();
    }

    /* Starts an appropriate intent or dialog for user interaction to resolve
     * the current error preventing the user from being signed in.  This could
     * be a dialog allowing the user to select an account, an activity allowing
     * the user to consent to the permissions being requested by your app, a
     * setting to enable device networking, etc.
     */
    private void resolveSignInError() {
        Log.d(TAG, "mSignInIntent(2): " + mSignInIntent);
        if (mSignInIntent != null) {
            // We have an intent which will allow our user to sign in or
            // resolve an error.  For example if the user needs to
            // select an account to sign in with, or if they need to consent
            // to the permissions your app is requesting.

            try {
                // Send the pending intent that we stored on the most recent
                // OnConnectionFailed callback.  This will allow the user to
                // resolve the error currently preventing our connection to
                // Google Play services.
                mSignInProgress = STATE_IN_PROGRESS;
                startIntentSenderForResult(mSignInIntent.getIntentSender(),
                        RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Sign in intent could not be sent: "
                        + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Attempt to connect to
                // get an updated ConnectionResult.
                mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Google Play services wasn't able to provide an intent for some
            // error types, so we show the default Google Play services error
            // dialog which may still start an intent on our behalf if the
            // user can resolve the issue.
            createErrorDialog().show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                    Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case RC_SIGN_IN:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // If the error resolution was successful we should continue
                    // processing errors.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_SIGN_IN;
                } else {
                    // If the error resolution was not successful or the user canceled,
                    // we should stop processing errors.
                    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                }

                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                    // If Google Play services resolved the issue with a dialog then
                    // onStart is not called so we need to re-attempt connection here.
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
        if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            mCirclesList.clear();
            PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
            try {
                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    mCirclesList.add(personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                }
            } finally {
                personBuffer.close();
            }

            mCirclesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error requesting visible circles: " + peopleData.getStatus());
        }
    }

    private void onSignedOut() {
        // Update the UI to reflect that the user is signed out.
        mSignInButton.setEnabled(true);
        mSignOutButton.setEnabled(false);
        mRevokeButton.setEnabled(false);

        // Show the sign-in options
        findViewById(R.id.layout_server_auth).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);

        mCirclesList.clear();
        mCirclesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason.
        // We call connect() to attempt to re-establish the connection or get a
        // ConnectionResult that we can attempt to resolve.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    private Dialog createErrorDialog() {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(mSignInError)) {
            return GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    mSignInError,
                    this,
                    RC_SIGN_IN,
                    new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services resolution cancelled");
                            mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                            mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(R.string.play_services_error)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.close,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    Log.e(TAG, "Google Play services error could not be "
                                            + "resolved: " + mSignInError);
                                    mSignInProgress = STATE_DEFAULT;
                                    mStatus.setText(R.string.status_signed_out);
                                }
                            }).create();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CheckResult onCheckServerAuthorization(String idToken, Set<Scope> scopeSet) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Checking if server is authorized.");
        Log.i(TAG, "Mocking server has refresh token: " + String.valueOf(mServerHasToken));

        if (!mServerHasToken) {
            // Server does not have a valid refresh token, so request a new
            // auth code which can be exchanged for one.  This will cause the user to see the
            // consent dialog and be prompted to grant offline access. This callback occurs on a
            // background thread so it is OK to do synchronous network access.

            // Ask the server which scopes it would like to have for offline access.  This
            // can be distinct from the scopes granted to the client.  By getting these values
            // from the server, you can change your server's permissions without needing to
            // recompile the client application.
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(SELECT_SCOPES_URL);
            HashSet<Scope> serverScopeSet = new HashSet<Scope>();

            try {
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                int responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

                if (responseCode == 200) {
                    String[] scopeStrings = responseBody.split(" ");
                    for (String scope : scopeStrings) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Server Scope: " + scope);
                        serverScopeSet.add(new Scope(scope));
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Error in getting server scopes: " + responseCode);
                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in getting server scopes.", e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in getting server scopes.", e);
            }

            // This tells GoogleApiClient that the server needs a new serverAuthCode with
            // access to the scopes in serverScopeSet.  Note that we are not asking the server
            // if it already has such a token because this is a sample application.  In reality,
            // you should only do this on the first user sign-in or if the server loses or deletes
            // the refresh token.
            return CheckResult.newAuthRequiredResult(serverScopeSet);
        } else {
            // Server already has a valid refresh token with the correct scopes, no need to
            // ask the user for offline access again.
            return CheckResult.newAuthNotRequiredResult();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUploadServerAuthCode(String idToken, String serverAuthCode) {
        // Upload the serverAuthCode to the server, which will attempt to exchange it for
        // a refresh token.  This callback occurs on a background thread, so it is OK
        // to perform synchronous network access.  Returning 'false' will fail the
        // GoogleApiClient.connect() call so if you would like the client to ignore
        // server failures, always return true.
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(EXCHANGE_TOKEN_URL);

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serverAuthCode", serverAuthCode));
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            final String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            Log.i(TAG, "Code: " + statusCode);
            Log.i(TAG, "Resp: " + responseBody);

            // Show Toast on UI Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            return (statusCode == 200);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in auth code exchange.", e);
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error in auth code exchange.", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void checkServerAuthConfiguration() {
        // Check that the server URL is configured before allowing this box to
        // be unchecked
        if ("WEB_CLIENT_ID".equals(WEB_CLIENT_ID) ||
                "SERVER_BASE_URL".equals(SERVER_BASE_URL)) {
            Log.w(TAG, "WEB_CLIENT_ID or SERVER_BASE_URL configured incorrectly.");
            Dialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(getString(R.string.configuration_error))
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();

            dialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am definitely sure that this error will be caused by not entering your(or entering incorrect) package name in the Google API console.

Just go through all the steps sincerely once again as noted [here](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/samples/quickstart-android) :

If you have created a new project, then also you must register a new Application(with package name and SHA1) in "Credentials" section of the Google Console API.

Hope it helps you :-)

Comment: Thank you sai, another pass through did the trick. My package name was wrong.

Comment: No  Problem dude, mistakes made me learn that too. Have a nice day :-)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have set a consent screen on your app and have selected an email in the project configuration.  The consent page can be found here:

`https://console.developers.google.com/project/<yourprojectid>/apiui/consent`

The email field is the one that, if not selected from the listbox, causes the error code 17 to be returned.